# Ant Design: How to transform field value?

Tags: antd

I noticed that in Ant Design Form, it's possible to set 'transform' for a specific validation rule, which will transform field value before the validation. But I'm wondering whether there's a way to apply a transform to field value when getting a response from `getFieldValue` or `validateFields`.

Here is an actual user case. I have a field that accepts multiple email addresses separated by comma, e.g, `"foo@example.com, bar@example.com"`. I've written a transform function which will transform string value of the field to `["foo@example.com", "bar@example.com"]`. I'd like to the field value to be the transformed email array instead of raw string when calling `getFieldValue`. And in `values` for `validateFields` callback, I'd like the field value to the transformed array as well.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Just want to point out that there is a substantial piece of additional docs at https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator, including `transform`. In case you missed the very small link on the antd page...

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that link. But my question has less thing to do with the validation, but I'd like this `transform` function to be applied in other use cases such as `getFieldValue`.

Comment: @RyanYe Did you found a solution?

Comment: Probably you could save ouput from "transform" to a state, and then get it back inside "getFieldValue" or "validateFields"